# Fetching uniprot seq using bash command

Tags: uniprot

I am trying to get a protein sequence using this command:

```
curl https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/A2Z669.fasta
```

But I don't get any output:

```
$ curl https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/A2Z669.fasta
$
```

And no file is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/A2Z669.fasta redirects to https://rest.uniprot.org/uniprotkb/A2Z669.fasta. You can see this if you open it in your browser: clicking on the first link will take you to the address of the second.

Now, `curl` [doesn't follow redirects by default](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/763548/22222), you need the `-L` option for that (see `man curl`):

> -L, --location
>
> (HTTP)  If  the  server  reports  that  the requested page has moved to a different location (indicated with a Location:
> header and a 3XX response code), this option makes curl redo the request on the new place. If  used  together  with  -i,
> --include or -I, --head, headers from all requested pages are shown.

So you need `-L` for `curl` to work here:

```
$ curl -L https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/A2Z669.fasta
>sp|A2Z669|CSPLT_ORYSI CASP-like protein 5A2 OS=Oryza sativa subsp. indica OX=39946 GN=OsI_33147 PE=3 SV=1
MRASRPVVHPVEAPPPAALAVAAAAVAVEAGVGAGGGAAAHGGENAQPRGVRMKDPPGAP
GTPGGLGLRLVQAFFAAAALAVMASTDDFPSVSAFCYLVAAAILQCLWSLSLAVVDIYAL
LVKRSLRNPQAVCIFTIGDGITGTLTLGAACASAGITVLIGNDLNICANNHCASFETATA
MAFISWFALAPSCVLNFWSMASR
```

Or, alternatively, you can use `wget` which does follow redirects by default:

```
$ wget "https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/A2Z669.fasta" 
--2023-12-10 16:21:46--  https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/A2Z669.fasta
Loaded CA certificate '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'
Resolving www.uniprot.org (www.uniprot.org)... 193.62.193.81
Connecting to www.uniprot.org (www.uniprot.org)|193.62.193.81|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://rest.uniprot.org/uniprot/A2Z669.fasta [following]
--2023-12-10 16:21:46--  https://rest.uniprot.org/uniprot/A2Z669.fasta
Resolving rest.uniprot.org (rest.uniprot.org)... 193.62.193.81
Connecting to rest.uniprot.org (rest.uniprot.org)|193.62.193.81|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://rest.uniprot.org/uniprotkb/A2Z669.fasta [following]
--2023-12-10 16:21:46--  https://rest.uniprot.org/uniprotkb/A2Z669.fasta
Reusing existing connection to rest.uniprot.org:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 314 [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘A2Z669.fasta.1’

A2Z669.fasta             100%[=======================================>]     314  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2023-12-10 16:21:47 (8.57 MB/s) - ‘A2Z669.fasta.1’ saved [314/314]
```

That creates a `A2Z669.fasta` file in the current directory which will contain the sequence.